# How to wrap a library async method with a threadsafe async wrapper in scala?

Tags: scala, concurrency, locking

I'm working with a library that has a method that looks something like this.

```
  trait LibraryDependency {
    /**
     * This method if called while previous future is not resolved will return a failed future
     * @return
     */
    def foo(): Future[Boolean]
  }
```

Here the method `foo()` will return a failed future if there is a previous future that was returned by `foo()` that has not yet completed. Since I cannot modify the library's implementation of the trait, I am trying to wrap it with my own wrapper that provides the behaviour I need.

The behaviour I need is that if there are concurrent calls to `foo()`, then the other futures will also block until the first future is resolved. I tried to do something like this.

```
  class ThreadSafeLibraryWrapper(delegate: LibraryDependency) extends LibraryDependency {
    private val lock: Object = new Object
    private implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    /**
     * This one will block the other concurrent calls to foo()
     * @return
     */
    override def foo(): Future[Boolean] = {
      val promise = Promise[Boolean]()

      lock.synchronized {
        val result = delegate.foo()
        promise.completeWith(result)

        result.onComplete { _ =>
          lock.notify()
        }

        lock.wait()
      }

      promise.future
    }
  }
```

I'm running into the following issue, I'm not sure how to block the thread that is calling this method, and complete the original future, and I get `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

EDIT: I've solved this by using `Await`

```
  class ThreadSafeLibraryWrapper(delegate: LibraryDependency) extends LibraryDependency {
    private val lock: Object = new Object
    private implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    /**
     * This one will block the other concurrent calls to foo()
     * @return
     */
    override def foo(): Future[Boolean] = Future {
      lock.synchronized {
        Await.result(delegate.foo(), Duration.Inf)
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm still not sure how to do this by avoiding `Await`.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, your dependency can run on `Future` at time, so you would like to have wrapper which will limit access to `foo` method so to avoid returning failed future. If so, this looks like you need to en-queue next invocations until previous one will complete.
Well, I did some prototyping and I hope it helps:

```
import java.time.LocalTime.now

import scala.collection.immutable.Queue
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future, Promise}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

object Concurrency {
  trait LibraryDependency {
    /**
     * This method if called while previous future is not resolved will return a failed future
     * @return
     */
    def foo(): Future[Boolean]
  }

  class DummyLibraryDependency(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends LibraryDependency {
    override def foo(): Future[Boolean] = {
      Future {
        println(s"${now()} - started dependency execution")
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println(s"${now()} - finished dependency execution")
        true
      }
    }
  }

  class SafeLibraryDependency(delegate: LibraryDependency)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {
    private type OnComplete = Try[Boolean] => Unit

    private var currentlyRunning: Option[Future[Boolean]] = None
    private var queue: Queue[Promise[Boolean]] = Queue[Promise[Boolean]]()

    def foo: Future[Boolean] = {
      this.synchronized {
        currentlyRunning.fold(startDelegateTask(onRunningComplete))(_ => enqueueNextTask())
      }
    }

    private def enqueueNextTask(): Future[Boolean] = {
      val promise = Promise[Boolean]()
      queue = queue enqueue promise
      promise.future
    }

    private def onRunningComplete(result: Try[Boolean]): Unit = {
      this.synchronized {
        currentlyRunning = None
        if(queue.nonEmpty) {
          val (promise, newQueue) = queue.dequeue
          queue = newQueue
          startDelegateTask { result =>
            promise.complete(result)
            onRunningComplete(result)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    private def startDelegateTask(f: OnComplete): Future[Boolean] = {
      val task = delegate.foo()
      task.onComplete(f)
      currentlyRunning = Some(task)
      task
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    val dummyLibraryDependency = new DummyLibraryDependency
    val safeLibraryDependency = new SafeLibraryDependency(dummyLibraryDependency)

    safeLibraryDependency.foo.onComplete(result => println(s"${now()} - #1 complete with result: $result"))
    safeLibraryDependency.foo.onComplete(result => println(s"${now()} - #2 complete with result: $result"))
    safeLibraryDependency.foo.onComplete(result => println(s"${now()} - #3 complete with result: $result"))

    Thread.sleep(5000)
    println("Done")
  }
}
```

So `SafeLibraryDependency` - this is the wrapper, which limit's invocations to single running `Future` at time.

On my machine output was next:

```
19:30:43.666 - started dependency execution
19:30:44.679 - finished dependency execution
19:30:44.681 - started dependency execution
19:30:44.679 - #1 complete with result: Success(true)
19:30:45.681 - finished dependency execution
19:30:45.681 - started dependency execution
19:30:45.681 - #2 complete with result: Success(true)
19:30:46.682 - finished dependency execution
19:30:46.682 - #3 complete with result: Success(true)
Done
```

Hope this helps you!